# Error using JSON object as property for Image source

Tags: javascript, json, image, react-native

so guys i have the path of images coming from a JSON File likes this

```
[
    {
        "name": "Cebola Roxa",
        "price": 4,
        "quantity": 0,
        "path": "../assets/productsImages/purpleonion.png"
    },
    {
        "name": "Cenoura",
        "price": 4,
        "quantity": 0,
        "path": "../assets/productsImages/carrot.png"
    },
]
```

The path for the images are correct, the problem is that when i try to use this path inside of o source using require it says Sintax Error

```
import products from '../assets/products.json'
const listProducts = products.map((product,index) => {

return( <Image source={require(product.path)} style={styles.imgProduct} />)
}
```

[image]

How can i load images using the path from a JSON file ?

Comment: can you try `"path": require("../assets/productsImages/purpleonion.png")` and `source={product.path}`

Comment: just tried and it gives me this error : Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `source` supplied 
to `Image`.

Comment: Can you try:
` <Image
        style={styles.imgProduct} 
        source={{
          uri: product.path
        }}
      />`

Comment: it doesnt give me any error, but also doesnt load any image

Comment: Hello guys i just did what Willian Wang recomended to me but instead of using a JSON file i used one JavaScript File and that worked ! thank you !